# git sparse checkout warning: unrecognized negative pattern

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I have clone the full repo before. so I run the following command.

```
cd main
git sparse-checkout init --cone
echo -e '/*\n!/client/*' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout
```

then the output

```
warning: unrecognized negative pattern: '/client/*'
warning: disabling cone pattern matching
Updating files: 100% (429011/429011), done.
```

and the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file:

```
/*
!/client/*
```

after checkout, the `client` dir is still there, I think it should not be there, where is something wrong? I read the blog https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/ and didn't get it. Could someone explain it， Thanks!

Comment: "Cone mode" generally requires trailing slashes, so the second line should read `!/client/*/` or (simpler) just `!/client/`. I haven't experimented with cone mode sparse checkout myself yet, though. Also, Git won't always remove an empty directory, so if you already (through non-sparse-checkout) had created `client/` and populated it with files, a sparse checkout that *doesn't* populate it might not *remove* it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of the cases where Git fails to remove a directory that it de-populates are bugs, but I've never found reliable reproducers with which to fix these bugs.

Comment: @nin What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @torek sorry to rely late. I tried serveral times and here is the colusion. under Cone mode, both `!/client/*/` and `!/client/` didn't help but as you says, I have already had created `client/` before so git didn't remove it but when use sparse checkout most the file in the dir will vanish which means the sparse checkout worked as expected and the `warning: unrecognized negative pattern` effect nothing and it could be neglected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VonC the git version is 2.33.3. as I said above, it seems to has nothing to do with the version

Comment: @ningyuwhut Just to be sure, can you try with git 2.38?

Comment: @VonC I tried git 2.38 on mac and it also gives the warning message

Comment: @ningyuwhut So maybe the warning is just here to mention a negative pattern is not compatble with the cone mode.

Comment: @VonC yes, but it doesn't effect the sparse checkout.